# draw only an arc by Qconicalgradient not full circle

Tags: c++, qt, gradient

I want to add canonical gradient to only an specific arc in my circle
but when I use `QCanonicalGradient` all my circle will be fill, I tried to make other parts transparent but canonical gradient interpolate between other part that i want to be transparent,
would you please help me how can I interpolate only specific arc with canonical gradient?
thank you in advance
here is my code :
( I want to interpolate between m_start and m_end)

```
QConicalGradient gradient( QPointF( m_xActualOuterRadius, m_yActualOuterRadius ), 0.0);
gradient.setColorAt(0.0, Qt::transparent);
gradient.setColorAt(m_startColor, Qt::transparent);
gradient.setColorAt(m_startColor, m_foregroundColor);
gradient.setColorAt(m_endColor, m_foregroundColor.lighter());
gradient.setColorAt(1.0, Qt::transparent);
```

Comment: Have you tried `painter->drawPie`?

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I’ve used it at that time but unfortunately I forgot to mark it as solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `drawPie()` method in `QPainter` with `QBrush` where installed gradient.

For example (I draw on pixmap, but you can choose something else):

```
QPixmap pixmap(325,215);

QPainter p(&pixmap);//we will paint on pixmap

QConicalGradient gradient( QPointF( 50, 50 ), 0.0);//your gradient
gradient.setColorAt(0.0, Qt::blue);//colors which you want
gradient.setColorAt(0.2, Qt::yellow);
gradient.setColorAt(0.4, Qt::red);
gradient.setColorAt(0.75,Qt::green);
gradient.setColorAt(1.0, Qt::magenta);
p.setBrush(QBrush(gradient));//set brush, it is our background and it will be gradient

    QRectF rectangle(10.0, 20.0, 80.0, 60.0);//preparation for drawPie method
     int startAngle = 30 * 16;
     int spanAngle = 120 * 16;
//it is from Qt documentstion, you can find best values for you
     p.drawPie(rectangle, startAngle, spanAngle);

    label->setPixmap(pixmap); //just show pixmap in label
```